# How Long Does HTML5 Web Storage API keep data?

Tags: html, mobile-application, web-storage, hybrid-mobile-app

I developed mobile web and hybrid applications with PhoneGap. I am using HTML5 Web Storage very often in my application.

I am wondering if there is a time limit for keeping data? How long do browsers keep Web Storage data? Until the user deletes it?